# Differences between query with SQL and without SQL in SparkSQL

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

during the learning of Spark 2 in Scala, I found that we can use two ways to query data in SparkSQL:

> 1. spark.**sql**(SQL_STATEMENT)  // variable "spark" is an instance of SparkSession
> 2. DataSet/DataFrame.**select/.where/.groupBy**....

My question is what are the **differences**(functional, performance, etc.) bewtween the them? 
I tried to find the anwser on internet or their documentation, but failed, so I would like to listen to your  opinions

Answer (score 2):

I think both the query with `SQL` query and without `SQL` query are equivalent and equal. Both of same are in internals and use same engines inside. But I would prefer to user without `SQL` queries which are easier to write and provide some level of type safety.

among these

```
  1.  spark.sql(SQL_STATEMENT) // variable "spark" is a SparkSession
  2.  DataSet/DataFrame.select/.where/.groupBy....
```

I would choose number 2 for most of the case since it provides some lavel of typesafe

Comment: that's not true, for example you cannot use subqueries in the `DataFrame` API.

Comment: Yeah thats true we cannot use subqueries in DataFrame Api forgot to mention. Thankyou

Comment: @ShankarKoirala Thank you for your opinion first, but i am wondering what is the reference of your opinion? Why di you know they use same engines inside ?

Comment: Here are some references https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/42027/rdd-vs-dataframe-vs-sparksql.html  and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35222539/spark-sql-queries-vs-dataframe-functions

Comment: @ShankarKoirala Thank you, haha, but it seems it's a dead loop

Comment: What do you mean by _typesafe_ in this context, what exactly is likely to go wrong...

Answer (score 1):

By using DataFrames which is a Java API one can debug the SQL statements by breaking them down into simple statements. This would help in better understanding.

The only thing that makes difference is what kind of underlying algorithm is used for grouping.
HashAggregation vs SortAggregation
HashAggregation would be more efficient than SortAggregation.
SortAggregation - Will sort the rows and then gather together the matching rows. O(n*log n) HashAggregation creates a HashMap using key as grouping columns where as rest of the columns as values in a Map. Spark SQL uses HashAggregation where possible(If data for value is mutable). O(n)