# Is there benefit in using aggregation operations over Dataframes than directly implementing SQL aggregations using spark.sql()

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am working in spark for  last 6 + months. I have seen people coming from Data warehousing and SQL backgrounds are implementing aggregations and other transformation logic in SQL using

```
spark.sql() 
(where spark is the sparkSession object)
```

directly over hive tables or after registering a Dataframe as a TempView using

```
dataframe.createOrReplaceTempView().
```

But if we see we have also other options like windows functions or alternatives which can be implemented directly over dataframes.Or even we can register a function as UDF and can be implemented over dataframe.

Say If I need to implement count of population group by City over a dataframe CITY_CENSUS I can implement in either of the below methods

using spark.sql():

```
CITY_CENSUS.createOrReplaceTempView("CITY_CENSUS")
spark.sql("select city,count(population) from CITY_CENSUS group by city")
```

OR using aggregation directly over dataframe:

```
CITY_CENSUS.groupBy("city").agg(count("population"))
```

Like this we have so many examples.

Is there any performance benefit in using the dataframe approach over spark.sql() or viceversa.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35222539/spark-sql-queries-vs-dataframe-functions

Answer (score 0):

The dataframe DSL will not handle all sub queries, currently. Using Spark SQL you will be able to tackle such situations beter. AGGRegations may need these as well, surely ...

UDFs are not optimizable by Catalyst and could result in less performant physical plans.